# How to convert a 2D Int array to a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

Trying to create a basic battleships game

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class BattleShip
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      //public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
      public static void breakln()
      {

   }


      public static void main(String[] arg)
      {
          int size = 0;   
          int[][] board = new int[5][5];
         createBoard(board);
         createShip(board, 4);
         BattleShip.createBoard(board);
         BattleShip.Display_Baord(board);
         BattleShip.createShip(board, size );

      }



      public static void createBoard(int[][] board){
          for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ )
              for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ )
                  board[row][column]=-1;
      }

      public static void Display_Baord(int[][] board){
          System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
          System.out.println
```

();

```
          for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ ){
              System.out.print((row+1)+"");
              for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ ){
                  if(board[row][column]==-1){
                      System.out.print("\t"+"~");
                  }else if(board[row][column]==0){
                      System.out.print("\t"+"*");
                  }else if(board[row][column]==1){
                      System.out.print("\t"+"X");
                  }

              }
              System.out.println();
          }

      }



      This is the method where the error is 

      public static void createShip(int[][] board,int size)
      {
         if(Math.random() < 0.5)
         {
            int col = (int)(Math.random()*5);
            int row = (int)(Math.random()*7);
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {
               board[row][col+i] = "S"; Hear is my error, i cannot have 's' as my 2d array ' board is an int
            }
         }
         else
         {
            int col = (int)(Math.random()*7);
            int row = (int)(Math.random()*5);
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            {
               board[row+i][col] = "S";    Hear is my error, it cannot be a string as 'board' is an int 
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

I'm just looking to find out how I can store 's' in my int 2D array Board.

Comment: Apologies for the spam of G, was to get around the 'lack of detail.

Comment: How about instead of getting around the lack of detail, you actually include some detail? You've pasted a massive code dump and asked a vague question without specifying what you actually want, what you've tried and what your problem is. I also highly doubt all this code is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "S" inside of your int array, use an int that you can extract later as a flag almost.

For example, it doesn't appear you are using negative numbers.

Instead of using "S", what about `-1`?

Then in your code instead of checking for "S" later on, you can check for `-1` and not have to worry about converting your entire array.